# Building iOS project with Jenkins on Ubuntu Linux

Tags: ios, jenkins

I have installed Jenkins in Ubuntu and while I am trying to build an iOS app in Jenkins the below error occurs:

> FATAL: Cannot find xcodebuild with the configured path /usr/bin/xcodebuild.

Comment: Have you configured your iOS job so that it always runs on a Mac?

Comment: Hi @ChristopherOrr

I have installed jenkins in ubuntu server, But i wanted to build ios app i this jenkins (ie installed in ubuntu), And it is searching for /usr/bin/xcodebuild which is not present in ubuntu server.
Is that jenkins to be installed in Mac itself to run ios build ? Or is there is any other way to run in ubuntu server itself ? 
Can you please help me on this bit confused.

Answer (score 67, accepted):

The `xcodebuild` tool is part of the Xcode SDK from Apple — it's only available for download on Mac OS X.
You cannot simply use the official iOS tools to build on a computer that isn't running OS X.

This means that, if you have a Jenkins job which builds an iOS app, it *must* be built on a Mac.

This does *not* mean, however, that Jenkins must be installed on a Mac.  Jenkins supports [distributed builds](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Distributed+builds), whereby you can have multiple machines, with different operating systems, and you can instruct Jenkins on which machine a certain build should run.

For example, as you already have a Ubuntu machine as your Jenkins master server, you can simply [add a Mac as a build node](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Distributed+builds#Distributedbuilds-Havemasterlaunchslaveagentviassh).  The Jenkins master  would then communicate with the build node (Mac) via SSH.  In the configuration for that build node, you should add a label, e.g. "xcode", to signify that the Xcode SDK is installed.

In the Jenkins job configuration, there is an option called "Restrict where this project can be run", where you can tell Jenkins that it may build this job only on a node with a given label.  In this case, you would just enter "xcode", and the job would always be built on an appropriate Mac, rather than on the Ubuntu machine.

Comment: A perfect answer. Thanks.

Comment: Hi, How about now in 2019, is there any way to run `xcodebuild` on linux vps ?

Answer (score 1):

As of Xcode 11, there is not a way to run the Xcode build tools on an operating system other than macOS. The minimum system requirements can be found [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode_release_notes/xcode_11_release_notes).

Comment: You can build swift projects pretty much anywhere now as it is open source. You just cannot installed xcode or build iOS projects from any other OS than a mac

Answer (score 1):

There is an opensource `xcodebuild` replacement made by Facebook called `xcbuild`. Running on MacOS, Linux and Windows.

https://github.com/facebook/xcbuild

But then again, Apple could see that you're not building on Mac hardware and wont allow your app to be on the appstore.