# How to configure IOS jobs in linux jenkins?

Tags: ios, jenkins

I want to configure IOS project jobs in linux jenkins. Is it possible to configure IOS jobs in Linux Jenkins, without OSX PC.

Comment: Duplicate of [Building iOS project with Jenkins on Ubuntu Linux](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31404884/fatal-cannot-find-xcodebuild-with-the-configured-path-usr-bin-xcodebuild)

Answer (score 0):

You need to have a OSX machine running. It's a matter of licensing (same problem appears for Visual Studio). But there is an XCode Plugin to help you with it [Jenkins Xcode Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Xcode+Plugin).

edit:
there are several tutorials out there on how to give jenkins an iOS-build slave ([check out one](http://savvyapps.com/blog/continuous-integration-ios-jenkins/)).