# Error fetching remote repo 'origin': Can't connect Jenkins to Git repository

Tags: git, jenkins, master-slave

I'm working to build an iOS project on jenkins and currently I'm facing an issue with CI-CD. Maybe somebody of you may help to resolve this issue.

Those are the steps in the CI-CD chain:

(1) Push code to Git  (2) Hook to Jenkins  (3) Push Code to a MacBook 
(4) Build App on MacBook   (5) Results back to Jenkins

Some further information:

- The steps I followed are available on this link: [Building iOS project with Jenkins on Ubuntu Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31404884/building-ios-project-with-jenkins-on-ubuntu-linux)
- The connection that Jenkins use to access to GitLab: API token.
- The connection between master(Jenkins) and the agent (Mac Node): SSH connection and it’s working
- In the job configuration, to affect a job to a node, there in  an option called “Restrict where this project can be run”, when I’m uncheck this option the connection between git and jenkins works correctly.

The issue is when I push the code on Gitlab and check the option "Restrict where this project can be run", I can't connect Jenkins to Git repository   I have the following message:

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fkOP4.png): [issue Error fetching remote repo 'origin'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fkOP4.png)

Comment: are you able to fetch the repo in some other directory in your machine where Jenkins is installed.., as per your error there is an issue in your ssl..

Comment: Thank you for your clarifications, I checked the certificate of Git already exist on the keychain of the MacBook .
I have the same error message, nothing was change;